# Multiple Call Async for update vector or list in C++

Tags: c++, asynchronous, vector, future

I am stuck in multiple Async problems like that
example:

```
void updateList(vector<int> &list, int value){
  list.push_back(value);
}

int main(){
   vector<future<void>> asyncTasks;
   vector<int> list;
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++){
      asyncTasks.push_back(async(launch::async, updateList,i ));
   }

   for(auto &&f : asyncTasks){
      f.get();
   }
}
```

The problem is sometimes it throws errors about insert violent.

Can you give me any ideas ?

Comment: Here's the basic idea. You cannot do this. Different tasks cannot change the same thing at the sme time.

Comment: @n.m do you have any ideas for this ?

Comment: You could use mutexes to control access, but since all the threads do is modify the same data structure only one thread will be able to operate at a time resulting in absolutely no performance increase. Worse, there is significant performance degradation from thread creation, overhead running the threads, the the threads fighting over the mutex. Not a good use-case for threading, I'm afraid.

Comment: @user4581301 
back to my problems, if the task return value , then I add to list at main thread after get(), is it able to do ?

Comment: You are trying to do an inherently sequential task in parallel. Don't do that! It doesn't work. What kind of problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Your problem is you need to control access to `list`. If you do not, the many threads all operating at the same time will blow the <expletive deleted> out of `list` by simultaneously adding items. Once you have [established control](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex), you can do whatever you want with the result. But the results can be done better and faster through [other means](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle).

Comment: @n.m. 
My problem is I have a list of files, and I want to read them asyn and add data into a map with format `map<string, vector<DataClass>>` 
I try to use Async, but there are some errors like @user4581301 said above.

Comment: @user4581301 My post is a sample for my problem. I will try `mutex` .
Thanks for your comment.

Comment: You are not going to speed up things with mutexes. I'm afraid you will see quite the opposite effect. A mutex makes access to your data structure sequential. The same thing can be done by not doing stuff in parallel in the first place.

Comment: @n.m. if that, any ideas for process files parallel and update into the global variable.

Comment: It can be hard to scan files in parallel. If you only have one regular hard disk, all of your threads will queue up waiting for access to that one hard disk and then access it one at a time. Depending on how long the processing of the files takes after reading you may see some improvement, but hard drives are pretty slow. All too often the reading takes most of the time.

Comment: Yes! Don't bloody do this in parallel. It's a waste of time.

Comment: @n.m.

Thanks for your comments and ideas.
Regards

Comment: In your `map<string, vector<DataClass>>`, are the keys to your map what you wish to parallelise over? I.e. is this a filename -> file contents map? You can have tasks which calculate individual `pair<string, vector<DataClass>>`s, and then have the main thread insert all the results into the map when all the tasks are done

Comment: I.e. use `vector<future<Result>>`, not `vector<future<void>>`, for some sensible `Result` type

Comment: @Caleth I also think about your given idea. It is also one possible solution.
But I tried to use `mutex` and it works fine now. 
Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Well the problem is that you are doing 2 things at once in `updateList`:

1. Calculating a value based on the index given (by calculation I mean just using it)
2. Adding a value to a container

Doing the second in parallel does not make much sense, since you would have to serialize on the container, otherwise you get data races, which is the reason for your errors.

```
void updateList(vector<int> &list, int value){
  list.push_back(value); //< Data race-> Undefined behavior -> Sometimes Crash 
}
```

But we can do the stuff which can be paralleled easily, namely 1. the calculation of a value.
If we just add dummy zeros in the container, at first, we are allowed to modify the elements in the container i.e. `std::vector`, since we don't modify the container it self, like count or order, only its members.

So after that you can calculate in parallel, but why not directly use the new parallel algorithms to do that for us? So I added a second solution.

Also this discovery that your work consists of work which can not be paralleled and work which can, can be found in **Amdahl's law**.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>
#include <future>


//Your modified solution
void updateList(std::vector<int> &list, int value){
    const auto index = value;
    //Do the heavy stuff here
    list[index]  = value;
}

int main(){

    std::vector<int> list(10);
    std::vector<std::future<void>> asyncTasks;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++){
        asyncTasks.emplace_back(std::async(std::launch::async, &updateList, std::ref(list), i));
    }
    for(auto &f : asyncTasks){
        f.get();
    }

    std::for_each(list.begin(),list.end(), [](auto v) {std::cout << v << " ";});
    std::cout << "\n";
}


//Better solution:

int heavy_work_calculation(int input) {
    //Do the heavy stuff here
    return input;
}

int main(){

    std::vector<int> list(10);
    std::iota(list.begin(), list.end(), 0);
    std::transform(std::execution::par_unseq, list.begin(), list.end(),
                    list.begin(), heavy_work_calculation);

    std::for_each(list.begin(),list.end(), [](auto v) {std::cout << v << " ";});
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank your given idea. I tried with `mutex` and the result is still fine now.
If there are any problems, I will try your solution.